# Use Xamarin Studio on Windows to build iOS app

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Is it possible to build an iOS app using Xamarin Studio running on Windows and have it connect to the Xamarin.ios Build Host running on the mac?

The [example I have seen](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/) only talk about using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not possible. Xamarin Studio on Windows will only build Android apps. If you are going to use Xamarin Studio and you have a connected Mac, then why not just use it on the Mac?

Comment: Generally, I prefer to develop in Windows. I feel more productive than on a Mac. Unfortunately, for the time being, it looks like I'll be developing on a Mac until I can buy the Business license to get VS support. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use Xamarin Studio on Windows and connect to the Xamarin.iOS build host, you have to use Visual Studio.

Just remember that you will need to do any design and layout tasks on Mac OS X using XCode  though. On Xamarin Studio for OS X Alpha Channel there is an interface builder but I think it does not apply to the Windows version of Xamarin Studio or the Visual Studio addon.

Comment: Can you point me to where the setting might be? I've installed Xamarin.iOS on my Windows machine but I don't see it on Xamarin Studio  `Tool` -> `Options`

Comment: Sorry I answered without proper testing. @valdetero is right. I already edited my answer and put it right.

Answer (score 0):

You can **write** iOS apps on windows but you can not **compile** them unless you have xcode on mac

Answer (score 0):

While not specifically answering the question, it should be noted that it is possible to develop for iOS in **Visual Studios** using a connected Mac as a build host. This connected Mac could either be through the network or can even be a **VM** running from your Windows machine.

You can now use the **Interface Builder inside of Visual Studios on Windows** to create iOS interfaces (only while connected to a Mac as described above).